# convert a string of full path to relative base url path

Tags: php, string, file, url

my problem is when i am uploading a file, it retrieve a full path like

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/public_html/gtc/wc-upload/gallery/
```

and where
(`C:/xampp/htdocs/public_html/gtc/`) is the root directory. it is required the full path string should be relative with base URL like this `http://gtc.app/wc-upload/gallery/`.
How could i reform the string like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php

$stringToFind = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/public_html/gtc/';

$path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/public_html/gtc/wc-upload/gallery/';

$url = 'http://gtc.app/';



$pos = strpos($path, $stringToFind);
if ($pos === 0) {
    $url .= substr($path,strlen($stringToFind));    
}

echo $url."<br />";
```

Comment: actually it is on localhost for now, but the problem arise again when i upload this to my web server. is their any alternate method which does not fix it, instead it just fixes the `/wc-upload/` only.

Comment: If you have in $path variable other paths you can  do it for all paths. You can also use getcwd() to determine your working directory

Answer (score 0):

finally work up with this

```
$stringToFind = getcwd() ;
$stringToFind = str_replace('\\', '/', $stringToFind);
$path = $image_data['file_path'];
$url = base_url();
$pos = strpos($path, $stringToFind);
if ($pos === 0) 
{
        $url .= substr($path,strlen($stringToFind)+1);    
}
```